# Can concrete roof tiles break spontaneously?

Tags: tile, roof

I recently discovered that one of the concrete tiles on our rooftop is broken, and the cause is not immediately apparent. Considering the tile's age, approximately 60 years, is it possible that the breakage occurred solely due to its age? I am concerned about the potential for similar incidents to occur in other areas of the roof with no way to predict them.

[image]

[image]

Comment: 60 year cement tile is past its life expectancy, so you're going to need to replace it in the near future anyway. Also, how to you know it was spontaneous and not something that struck it?

Comment: It could also be that it cracked years (decades even) ago, and gradually over time due to weathering finally broke apart.

Comment: Spontaneous with the effects of uneven heating / cooling cycles.

Answer (score 2):

I'd have a hard time thinking it just cracked for the heck of it. They usually crack because someone stepped on it while pressure cleaning the roof or it could have cracked during installation and just now broke and separated. You can get a roof tile adhesive and fix this. Squeeze the adhesive into the crack and gently tap the bottom of the tile back in place.  As long as the membrane covering the roof deck isn't leaking, there's no reason to replace the roof.